# How to test a Silverlight application?

Tags: testing

I am testing a **silver light 3.0** application. I need to measure its performance and usability kind of things.. i have already searched some of the tools but yet to find the right one.

Could anyone help me in doing the above thing?

Comment: the way this site works is if an answer is the correct one you need to click on the tick so that other people can see the solution and apply the same to their own problems

Answer (score 0):

if you have developed this with good seperation of concerns, then you should be able to run tests against the backend code that doing the actual work.

So create a test project, create some mocks and run the tests 1,000 times.

The UI, other than functional testing, should not need to be stress tested IMHO.

As for usability, show some people or engage a 3rd party to take a look at the UI and give recomendations on what you could improve, if anything, to make it more usable.

Comment: ok griegs..  thanks for the comments. .will do it and tell the result of it